# how to hide one dropdown value another dropdown in angular?

Tags: angular

> I use the same list to load ghat. But I want to see that is when I select fromghat that selected value don't show in the toGhat.

> I use reactive form. Add TypeScript file and add HTML file also.

> I try myself but don't work properly.

> component.ts

```
export class ETicketingVesselComponent implements OnInit {
  ghatForm!: FormGroup;
  ghats: Ghat[] = [];
  constructor(
    private eTicketingStorageService: ETicketingStorageService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.eTicketingStorageService.readGhats().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.ghats = res;
        console.log('vessel' + res);

      },
    });
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ghatForm = this.fb.group({
      vesselId: [''],
      fromGhatId: ['', Validators.required],
      toGhatId: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

> html

```
 <nz-card>
            <div class="ng-Header col-xs-12"><i nz-icon nzType="file-search" nzTheme="outline"></i> Available Launch </div>
            <div class="searchboxAerar">
              <form nz-form [formGroup]="ghatForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(ghatForm.value)">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-1"> </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <nz-form-label nzFor="Vessel">Vessel</nz-form-label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                      <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select Vessel">
                        <nz-select id="vesselId" nzShowSearch nzAllowClear formControlName="vesselId"
                          nzPlaceHolder="Select Vessel" class="row">
                          <nz-option *ngFor="let vessel of vessels" [nzValue]="vessel.vesselId"
                            [nzLabel]="vessel.vesselNameEnglish">
                          </nz-option>
                        </nz-select>
                      </nz-form-control>
                    </div>
        
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <nz-form-label nzRequired nzFor="Ghat">From Ghat</nz-form-label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                      <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select Ghat">
                        <nz-select id="fromGhatId" nzShowSearch nzAllowClear formControlName="fromGhatId"
                          nzPlaceHolder="Select Ghat" class="row">
                          <nz-option *ngFor="let ghat of ghats" [nzValue]="ghat.id" [nzLabel]="ghat.name">
                          </nz-option>
                        </nz-select>
                      </nz-form-control>
                    </div>
        
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <nz-form-label nzRequired nzFor="Ghat">To Ghat</nz-form-label>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        
                      <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select Ghat ">
                        <nz-select id="toGhatId" nzShowSearch nzAllowClear formControlName="toGhatId"
                          nzPlaceHolder="Select Ghat" class="row">
                          <nz-option *ngFor="let ghat of ghats" [nzValue]="ghat.id" [nzLabel]="ghat.name">
                          </nz-option>
                        </nz-select>
                      </nz-form-control>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nz-card>
```

> this image show fromghat.
> [image]

> This image show toghat.
> [image]

Comment: Provide a minimal code like what you have tried so far.

Comment: Dear sir, i add HTML and TypeScript files. And i use the reactive form

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using ReactiveForms Module or template driven forms

Imagine that you has a list of Ghat. One select is

```
<select [(ngModel)]="fromGhat">
   <option *ngFor="let ghat of listGhats" [value]="ghat>{{ghat}}
   </option>
</select>
```

The other one

```
<select [(ngModel)]="fromGhat">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ghat of listGhats">
   <option *ngIf="ghat!=fromGhat" [value]="ghat>{{ghat}}
   </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

If you're using a FormGroup  you can has some like

```
<select formControlName="fromGhat">
   <option *ngFor="let ghat of listGhats" [value]="ghat>{{ghat}}
   </option>
</select>
```

The other one

```
<select formControlName="fromGhat">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ghat of listGhats">
   <option *ngIf="ghat!=myForm.get('fromGhat').value" [value]="ghat>{{ghat}}
   </option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

If the formGroup is a FormGroup in a FormArray possible your comparision should be some like

```
*ngIf="gath!=myForm.get('formArray.name.'+i+'.fromGhat').value!=gath"
```

Comment: This code does not work for my reactiveform.

Comment: The idea is that you use a `ng-container` to loop and a `*ngIf` to show only the option not choose (you can not use in the same "tag" a *ngFor and a *ngIf -ng-container **not** create a new tag) What is the condition? `*ngIf="ghatForm.value.fromGhatId!=ghat.id"`